# What does it mean Shan't & won't

Tags: grammar

What does it mean and what is different between Shan't & won't 
I need the answer with example

thank you

Comment: What time period and dialect of English are you asking about? In the U.S. today, the difference is that *"shan't"* is never used, and *"won't"* is commonly used. If this question was inspired by some uses in context, it would help to give them.

Comment: @ geezanansa: If you believe there is only one definition of "shall" and "will", and it is true for the entire English-speaking world, you are incorrect. Shakespeare made one distinction between "shall" and "will".  [H. W. Fowler](http://www.bartleby.com/116/213.html) and many 19th century inhabitants of the south of England made a different distinction between "shall" and "will" Fowler's distinction makes no sense whatsoever to contemporary Americans, who have mostly stopped using "shall", and the usage has apparently changed in England, so Fowler's advice also no longer applies there.

Comment: Apologies.  Nice comment.  How about adding the historical evidence as answer? My older pocket dictionary does not list "shan't" but newer dictionaries do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In British English, "shan't" is used as a denial of permission while "won't" is just a statement of fact.
In American English, "won't" is used in both cases while "shan't" is very rarely used.

Comment: Well, not exactly "fact". _Will_ is a statement of prediction. And you're correct that American't rarely use _shan't_. That's because they rarely use _shall_. In American English, _shall_ is used only in the first person, in two constructions, both indirect questions: (1) in the singular, as an offer to do something for the addressee: _Shall I open the window?_; (2) in the plural, as an invitation to participate in some activity with the speaker: _Shall we dance?_

Comment: I don't recognise this "Brits use *shan't* as a denial of permission". In what context? We say *"No you won't!"* and *"No you don't!"*, but I never heard anyone outside Victorian period drama on TV saying *"No you shan't!"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers As in "You shall not do that!"

Comment: @TrevorD: I know how it *used* to be used, and what it *means*. I'm just saying it's antiquated, and very uncommon today - I don't accept katalin_2003's assertion that it's British as opposed to American usage. It's practically ***archaic***, imho.

Comment: @FumbleFingers i never said it's British only. If you read the second paragraph, i said "shan't" is very rarely used in American English.

Comment: @ katalin_2003: But it's rarely used in *British* English - maybe not *quite* so rarely, but not sufficiently often to justify juxtaposing the fact that we "use" it (to a very limited degree) with the fact that Americans use it even less. It's outdated, not "British".

Answer (score 5):

(To understand the use of shan't and won't  let  us look at the definition  of shall  and will..  Please look in your own dictionaries. Additionally have a look at  Peter Shor's  link in his comment to question. 
katalan_2003 has hit the nail on the head as shall is used in  orders and commands as the definitions in your dictionaries will enlighten you this is the case.
I will share usage notes  regarding this from my dictionary  as  observing people being adamant about something which they do not have knowledge of makes them appear deluded.

USAGE: The traditional  rule is that when forming the future tense, shall should be used with I and we (I shall be late),  while will should be used with  you, he,  she,, it and they (he will not  be there) .  However when telling someone  what to do or showing determination  this rule is reversed: will is used with I and we (I will not tolerate this) and shall is used with you, he, she, and they (you shall go to school).
Nowadays people do not follow these rules so strictly and are more likely to use the shortened forms I'll , she'll etc, especially when speaking.

So now we all acknowledge the existence of  shall and will and have accurate knowledge of their use we could learn how to use them if we don't already.

An example of using shan't  (I shan't be late)
An example of using won't  (I won't tolerate this)